# Android R Class

Tags: android, android-studio, updates

As of the Android Studio 1.2 Update, my R class uses are broken without description and I can't import it. Alt+Enter is giving me no helpful suggestions. I have

```
import com.example.myname.myapp.R;
```

on one file I need and the R is red-underlined and my use of it (in the generated file) is broken too, as seen

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

under the onCreate method. I'm not understanding what's happening. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Try cleaning your project (Build -> Clean Project) and restart Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think that would be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was clean my project and restart Android Studio. Thanks, Jerry!

Answer (score 0):

The `R` class is created in some other directory in Android Studio:

That means `import` statement must be different, 
it depends on your current project name, for example:

```
import de.my-web-address.myapp-name.R;
```